# Duplicate interface definition for class 'PFFacebookUtils' - IOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Parse on an existing project, and after spending hours I cannot make it compile. I want to use FB with Parse, and I have tried the following.

**Pod file**

```
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
```

which adds :

```
Using Bolts (1.2.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (4.3.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (4.3.0)
Using Parse (1.7.5)
Installing ParseFacebookUtilsV4 (1.7.5)
```

**Importing**

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

**Error :**

```
@interface PFFacebookUtils : NSObject Duplicate interface definition for class 'PFFacebookUtils'
```

Even if I add in my import :

```
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

The error remains the same.

Comment: Any luck? I'm stuck here too.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Only difference is I have 440 build failures from Xcode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180650/pod-update-results-in-duplicate-interface-definition-for-class-xxx-for-all-aws

Comment: I had the same issue.  I discovered I had imported the framework and added my local path to the local version of the framework to the 'framework search paths' in the build phases.  This is fine if you're not using cocoapods, but if you are, this is redundant and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download any Facebook SDK to your hard drive and add the path to it to your 'framework search paths' configuration in your project? If you did this, then remove the framework and remove the path from the framework search paths.  This does not need to be done if you're importing it with cocoapods.