# pod update results in "duplicate interface definition for class xxx" for all AWS SDK (El Capitan + XCode 7)

Tags: cocoapods, xcode7, aws-sdk, osx-elcapitan, aws-sdk-ios

Just now, I updated my AWS SDK pods, which I regretted so much. I first saw this when pods were being updated:

> dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../../../../../../../SharedFrameworks in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../..//DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTInstrumentsFoundation being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
>   dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
>
> dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
>
> dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/Xcode3Core being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path

Then when I opened my project and build, I got so many so many build failures, complaining the same thing **Duplicate interface definition for class XXX**:

[image]

I have tried many solutions, reinstall AWS SDK pods, reinstall cocoapods, downgrade cocoapods to 0.38.2, downgrade AWS SDK pods to 2.2.6, but none helps. If I comment out the imports in Objective-C bridge header, I don't have these errors but Xcode just complaints about not finding some of the classes used in the codes. But I don't think commenting them out is the right solution. 
[image]

Well, I searched https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4302, and it seems it could be cocoapods' problem?

Anyone has any idea on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer (hopefully :))**

- remove the #import from the bridging header
- add "import AWSS3" (or whichever class you need) in the appropriate Swift files

**Explanation**

Since version 0.36 of Cocoapods, you don't need to import pods via the bridging header if they are in Swift code OR if they declare "use_frameworks!" (which AWS did in their version [2.2.1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#221)

**Edit**

In my case, I replaced "pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2', '~> 2.0'" with "pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.2.0'" and added "#import " in the bridging file.

Comment: Yes, I find it out also. Thanks!